# JavaScript drag n drop XY location when dropped is off due to point in drag element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drag-and-drop, html5-draggable

I am trying to create a drag and drop application when I can drop a marker on an image.  While this is an Angular app I am using plain old JS API for the drag and drop do to issues with `CDK`.

I am able to move a `20x20` div around the image and drop it and set the location on the image by setting the top/left style of the div.  However, the problem I am having is that the `offset[XY]` is the point of the mouse down.  So if I grab the upper left corning my div lands where I expect.  If I grab the div in the middle, then it is off by the drag point offset.

How can I correct for this offset of the draggable? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

One of my coworkers came up with a great solution.  Subscribe to the mousedown event to find the offset and then do the math.